# Why doesn't socket.io connect in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, sockets

My server is made on nest.js version 10. Below is a service for initializing websockets

```
@WebSocketGateway({ cors: true })
export class WebsocketsService implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
  @WebSocketServer()
  server: Server;
  private logger: Logger = new Logger('WebSockets');

  afterInit() {
    this.logger.log('Init');
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
    this.logger.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
  }

  handleConnection(client: Socket) {
    this.logger.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
  }
}
```

The server runs on url http://localhost:8072
Here is an example of how I connect socket.io to viewTask.component in the created() hook

```
created() {
  this.socket = io('http://localhost:8072', {
    path: '/socket.io',
    transports: ['websocket'],
    reconnectionDelay: 3000,
    reconnectionDelayMax: 6000,
    timeout: 30000
  });
},
```

I have the error

```
websocket.js?3277:39 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8072/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

How to fix the error? Why can't the client connect to the server?

Comment: This is specific to the backend, Vue is irrelevant. You should be able to reproduce this from browser console. It means what it says, localhost:8072/socket.io is not available.

Comment: But how to understand the reason for it? I created a separate project with exactly the same code, it works there. What could be the reason?

Comment: A separate project is backend or frontend? You need to isolate the problem. Currently it looks like it's backend, while you asked about frontend. It's unknown why you expect  localhost:8072/socket.io to exist. The question should contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide enough info to reproduce the problem, otherwise you're the only person who can resolve it